# tikz code for frame dragging

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'll appreciate suggestions for a code that create the following nice visualization of frame-dragging (or anything alike):

[image]

Comment: Also, please don't just post a picture and say "I want to draw this": Show what you've tried so far, and explain where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: Werner and Jack, please see my acomment to percusse below. I think my question was very clear, I asked for a code to start with. The suggestion below is just what I needed.

Comment: @user1999: Of course the question is clear, but the way it is now, it is also a bit selfish: This is a very localised problem that's only likely to benefit you. If you had done a bit of research yourself, you probably could have figured out a way to get started yourself. Then you could have asked a more widely applicable question ("How do I loop over two variables at once?", for instance). Since you say that "the suggestion below is just what I needed", why don't you also accept it?

Comment: @user1999: No problem. @ percusse explained the way this community usually operates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just for the sake of answering with something instead of letting it linger in the unanswered list. Since your accept rate is zero and this is a [draw-it-for-me](/questions/tagged/draw-it-for-me) question, your future questions are also unlikely to be answered. Please consider improving your stats and question formulation.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
\pgfmathparse{1-atan(\x)/90}
\xdef\rotang{\pgfmathresult}
\node[draw,circle,minimum height=\x cm,rotate=7/\x*\rotang r] (n-\x) at (0,0) {};
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {22.5,45,...,360}{
\coordinate (l-\x-\yi) at (n-\x.\y) {};
    }
}
\foreach \yi [count=\y]in {22.5,45,...,360}
    \draw[thick] (l-1-\y) to[in=175+\yi,out=105+\yi] (l-2-\y)
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \nextx using {int(\x+1)} ] in {3,4,...,8}{
           --(l-\x-\y) -- (l-\nextx-\y)  
        } -- (l-10-\y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really fancy! Although I guess the more "pedagogic" thing to do would have been to wait for a day or two to see if the OP adds new information, and if they don't to close the question as "Too localized". Now they got what they wanted, why wouldn't they post another `draw-it-for-me` question in the future?

Comment: This is really awesome. I didn't have a clue how to start (my knowledge in tikz is of order zero...) Thanks a lot. I'll play a bit with the parameters and learn how to alter the graphics according to my exact needs. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1999 Did you also read what I have written in the intro of my answer?

Comment: Yes, of course. Sometimes you do not know where to start. In this case you just ask for a starting point and hope someone finds it an interesting challenge so both sides benefit. And sometimes one gives help just for the sake of giving help... I admit it happenes to me once in a while...

Comment: But I did accept your answer :( and I did it willingly and with a lot of gratitude!

Comment: @user1999 I knew that there is a communication problem :) First of all thank you for your voting. You might have upvoted my answer but accepting is performed by finding a checkmark next to my answer and clicking it. Please just for the sake of it [click this link and read further](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764) to find out what is meant by **accepting** and how it differs from **upvoting**. Again, thank you for upvoting and sorry for this insisting behavior of mine. If that clarifies please do the same for your old questions too.

Comment: o.k. I'm sorry, I was not aware of the difference between upvoting and accepting... Upologies also to Werner for the missunderstanding.

Comment: @user1999 No problem at all. Thank you very much for accepting the answer. It would be great if you can also do the same for your previous questions. [Here is a list of them](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1999/user1999?tab=questions&sort=newest). Notice the accepted one has a darker background in the answers column. :)

Comment: with pleasure... now I see that people have already noticed me about acceptance in the past, but I did not get it :)